# How to copy DataTable from Database without changing the RowState Property Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, rowstate

I am filling my datatable from databse sa

```
var z = from ins in cstmrDC.customersCntcts_rd(101)
        select ins;
foreach (var dtbl in z)
{
    DataRow drDtls;
    drDtls = dtDtls.NewRow();
    drDtls[0] = dtbl.cust_Slno;
    drDtls[1] = dtbl.cust_Cntctnm;
    drDtls[2] = dtbl.cust_Cntctdesig;
    drDtls[3] = dtbl.cust_Cntctmobl;
    drDtls[4] = dtbl.cust_Cntctmail;
    //drDtls.RowState = DataRowState.Unchanged; 
    dtDtls.Rows.Add(drDtls);
}
```

In this way I can fill my `DataTable`, but the `RowState` of the `DataTable` is set to `Added` by default. But I want to manipulate these records from `DataGridView`.

Without changing the `RowState`, how can I insert, delete and update my `DataGridview`? Help me to fill the data table directly from the database.

I tried using `CopyToDataTable()` that is apperaring in my IntelliSense box. Maybe this is because I am using .Net 3.5.

Please Help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```cs
...
dtDtls.Rows.Add(drDtls);
dtDtls.AcceptChanges();
...
```

and `RowState` will be `Unchanged`.